# Can we restore mysql db without .ibd & .frm files?

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery

I have a data folder and the database folder with .frm & .ibd files is missing, any way to restore the database?

Currently the data folder has:

- ibdata1
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1

Comment: First, what is the setting `innodb_file_per_table`? On or off?

Comment: the recovery could be possible, but it's too little of information.

Comment: The application was deployed way back in 2013 using wamp 2.4 in client machine.

Comment: In my.ini there is no variable set for innodb_file_per_table, seems like it was off and all data is stored in ibdata1

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used the innodb_file_per_table option. In this case I'm afraid that there is no way to restore the database only from the ibdata1 and the two ib_logfiles, which are actually the innodb redo log files.

Comment: In the data folder that was taken as a backup, there was no folder with the database name! is that possible?

Comment: How does your real data-folder look like? How did you perform the backup?

Comment: In the backup the client have just copied the whole wamp folder.

Comment: then innodb_file_per_table isn't set. In this case all data is stored within the ibdata1 file.

Comment: Don't forget it's ON by default in 5.6

Comment: Any way to restore it @acanthinura? I tried by reinstalling the wamp 2.4 version & replacing the mysql data folder with the backup folder but there is error coming while logging in phpmyadmin "#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

Comment: you should try to connect to the database in a more basic way. mysql console client fir example. please paste your mysql error log here so we can see where the problem really is.